# React Native Track Player - Missing Native Module on IOS

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development, react-native-track-player

The native module which is accessed inside trackPlayer.ts in the RNTP package seems to be undefined, which causes the error: `new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument.`

```js
const { TrackPlayerModule: TrackPlayer } = NativeModules;
const emitter =
Platform.OS !== 'android'
? new NativeEventEmitter(TrackPlayer) //\<-- TrackPlayer is undefined
: DeviceEventEmitter;
```

I installed the latest version
`npm install --save react-native-track-player`

then I added playback-service.js

```js
import TrackPlayer, {Capability} from 'react-native-track-player';

module.exports = async function () {
  return async () => {
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play', () => TrackPlayer.play());
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-pause', () => TrackPlayer.pause());
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-next', () => TrackPlayer.skipToNext());
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-previous', () => TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious());
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('playback-buffering', (event) => {
      console.log('Buffering...', event.isBuffering);
    });

    await TrackPlayer.updateOptions([
      capabilities: [
        Capability.Play,
        Capability.Pause,
        Capability.SkipToNext,
        Capability.SkipToPrevious,
        Capability.JumpForward,
        Capability.JumpBackward,
        Capability.SeekTo
      ]
    });

    TrackPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
  }
};
```

registered the playback service and set up the player in App.tsx

```js
useEffect(() =\> {
TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() =\> require('./playback-service.js'));
TrackPlayer.setupPlayer()
}, \[\]);
```

after that I ran `cd ios && pod install`

Comment: Did you rebuild your app after that?

Comment: @Wodin yes, I did rebuild after that.

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding `pod 'react-native-track-player', path: '../node_modules/react-native-track-player'` to PODFILE under the ios folder fixed the issue.

Comment: See also the `extraPods` option of Expo's Build Properties config plugin
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/#pluginconfigtypeios